# Flutter: non-asset local image

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-assetimage, flutter-path

I'd like to include images in my Flutter application which are not asset images.

Let me clarify a bit. I am working with an embedded Unity application inside the Flutter app. I can communicate bidirectionally and part of the communication is sending a file location from Flutter to Unity, such that the Unity app can read that image and do something with it (e.g. a texture). But since assets are not directly accessible by location, I cannot give the path to the Unity part of the application.

**So would there be a way to include images in the app and reference them by old school path?**

Comment: you mean you want to get that file frimo the device ?

Comment: No idea what frimo means but yes I want the actual path of that file